# SQL Server query coding in master detail table

Tags: sql-server, database

I have two tables `master` and `detail`

`Master` table has columns:

```
id primary 
mmrec
billno
billdate
billtype
name 
address
amount
```

`Details` table has columns:

```
id primary
purchrecno - master>mmrec
itemcode
itemqty
amount
transtype (There will always be 4 types for this )
taxtype
```

Besides there is a `tax` table which has

```
taxcode primary
taxdesc
percent
```

What I want to achieve is a summary report, which will have four rows as per `billtyp`

There will be two sets of columns having twice as many columns as `taxtype` that were used in a particular period. One set will display base amount (this will be sum of amount for a particular type of tax) another set will have sum of tax (tax is calculated using percent from tax table on amount so that base amount  + tax amount equals to amount ( in details table)

obviously `Master` table will provide id to select `details` table transaction and provide
date for the `details` table transaction

`tax` table will provide tax information, and percent for tax calculation.

What I have conceived is there will 4 union for each `transtype`.

But somehow or other could not work out properly.

And I need your help in coding this query.

I am open to using a stored procedure or view but would prefer a query will get me 4 rows.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Comment: provide some code dear

Comment: please post some data representation & the report output as per your expectation

Comment: @ram.bi
I have created a doc containing example but not sure how to attach it. Besides as it contains formatted table and data char limit will
not allow me to add this.

Comment: You can just edit the question above paste there your example.